# Powershell: Define set local variable as array

Tags: powershell

I have a question. I have a setup where I have a parent BAT file that invokes some subroutines I've built, and I'm trying to figure out how to get something particular to work. The short version, in my main BAT file I have this:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "deleteThese = '*.PDF', '*.BMP', '*.AVI', '*.MOV', '*.PS1'
call "Subroutines\Find Folders and Remove Files of Extension.bat"
```

And what I'm looking for is when it invokes the second BAT file, I want it to pass the array to the environment variable. I thought I had it set up the right way to do that:

```
$deleteThese=$Env:deleteThese
```

But it's not working quite right. If I specify the deleteThese variable in the subroutine itself, it works fine; if I try to set it in the parent BAT file, it fails out and doesn't do anything. It doesn't even reach the PAUSE flag at the end of the batch file.

This is the syntax in the subroutine BAT file that actually pulls the values and clears the requested files:

```
$rootPath=$Env:rootPath
$searchFolder=$Env:searchFolder
$deleteThese=$Env:deleteThese

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory -Filter $searchFolder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Recurse -Include $deleteThese | 
    Remove-Item -Verbose
}
```

What am I missing? (Yes I know I could just loop it with a different file extension each time but that seems like it's overcomplicating things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Include` parameter expects an *array* of strings, but environment variables can only contain a *single string value each* - so you'll need to split the value into an array before passing it to `Get-ChildItem -Include`.

In the calling batch file, set the variable (exactly) like this - no single-quotes, and no spaces around `=`:

```
set "deleteThese=*.PDF,*.BMP,*.AVI,*.MOV,*.PS1"
```

Then, in the PowerShell script, make sure to split it into an array of individual strings:

```
$deleteThese = $Env:deleteThese.Split(',')
```

Now `Get-ChildItem -Include $deleteThese` will work as expected